# Why can I not log in to Stack Exchange Android app using a Google account?

Tags: discussion, android-app, login, google-openid

I recently installed the Stack Exchange app from Google Play Store, and every time I tried to log in to my account from the application using Google account, it shows me unable to verify your Google account. Although I have no problem when login from the browser.

Why?

Comment: 1) Are you using the same Google Account on the phone as your StackExchange login on browser? 2).Have you tried clearing the data (or uninstall & reinstall)?

Comment: thank you @ Morrison Chang yes i am using the same account .no i did not uninsatall but the app is newly installed.

Comment: Hmm, just tried to login to StackExchange app from a second phone, while it did give me  an error on the first attempt, I was able to hit the back button, and then from the login screen the second time through the app was able to access my account.

Comment: Issues with Stack Exchange apps are more suitable on [meta.se]. That said, the development of SE apps has been completely stopped, so there might be no official support anymore.

Comment: @Meta actually they're not suitable even here anymore, they get closed and deleted. Times changed, and the app is totally dead. The fact people still use it is a miracle. :-)